# Flutter widget test finds hint text in TextFormField without the field getting focus

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

I have a TextFormField on a page like below.

**Without focus**
[image]

**With Focus**
[image]

For this, I am writing a widget test.
Widget test code,

```
testWidgets('Testing title form field', (tester) async {
  await tester.pumpWidget(createAddTransactionPage());
  expect(find.text('Title'), findsOneWidget);
  expect(find.text('Enter a title...'), findsNothing); // Test fails due to this
});
```

By default, the expectation is the "hint text" is hidden and hence `findsNothing` should work.
Why is flutter widget tests finding a hidden text.
Is this a bug or am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bug https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/26336

As a workaround, you can use the `bySemanticsLabel` to resolve.

```dart
  Semantics(
    explicitChildNodes: true,    // <-- this is key point
    child: TextFormField(
      decoration: const InputDecoration(
        hintText: 'Enter a title',
        border: InputBorder.none,
      ),
      initialValue: asset.remark,
      onChanged: (value) => remark.value = value,
    ),
  ),
```

and then

```dart
find.bySemanticsLabel('Enter a title')
```